# Time.now - 1.hour.ago => 3599.999604?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
irb(main):012:0> Time.now - 1.hour.ago
=> 3599.999604
```

What's the code evaluation that causes this?

I understand the 2 code paths are evaluated here, I assume that ruby at first calculated the expression, then evaluates the `1.hour.ago` expression and only then the `Time.now` expression. The time difference between the 2 is the time it takes for the ruby interpreter to run the evaluations.

Comment: Time is not a fixed value, you cannot get precise and perfect time, it takes time to calculate `Time.now` itself Note: I didn't downvote you and I don't think this deserves a downvote

Comment: if you want to test this kind of behavior you can look at [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes a tiny but non-zero amount of time to determine what the time right now is. In this case the difference is 395µs. A quick test with Ruby 2.3.1 on my machine shows a difference of 16µs which is more like what I'd expect. I'm not sure why it's taking so long to compute the local time on your machine, but it could be just a random thing.

If you want an *exact* value, try this:

```
Time.now - 1.hour
```

Keep in mind that time is totally crazy and "one hour ago" might mean two hours ago, or zero hours ago, or maybe something else entirely depending on when you call this code. Daylight Saving confuses everything it touches.

Comment: OK.. that's super important. Any "better" way to do time calculations in ruby that is timezone / DST independent?

Comment: It depends on what you want. If you want chronologically one hour earlier then you can do the math this way, just don't expect 1am to be one hour before 2am consistently, or even in the same time zone. If you want to adjust the time one hour earlier on the clock you might want to use ActiveSupport or some other library to help do those calculations, but be aware some times simply don't exist, like 1:30am might not be a valid time in some time zones on some days.

Comment: I strongly recommend using UTC values internally and only rendering those out in local time as necessary. This is especially important in a database where you might move the server from one time zone to another where you might switch datacentres or local laws could arbitrarily change.

Comment: which API's of ruby are correct to do time calculations in UTC fashion, given that ActiveSupport is available ?

Comment: You get the entire [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) handling library, plus a whole [pile of extensions to the core Time class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html), where [`advance`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-advance) and [`change`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-change) are particularly handy for tasks like this.

Comment: in slight 3.years.ago delay :) thanks for all the help, marking the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only ruby. Your operating system can also interupt your programm and cause a huge gab between `1.hour.ago`  and  `Time.now`

You can prevent it by freezing the reference time

```
t = Time.now
t - 1.hour.ago(t)
```